# ASP.NET Core 3 MVC Routing parameters not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Feel like I'm doing something silly here, I'm playing around with ASP.NET Core 3 (MVC), doing some tutorials, getting familiar - and I'm having some issues specially with routing.

I have the below code in my `Startup.cs` attempting to setup a route of `Main/Home/{team}`.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews(mvc => mvc.EnableEndpointRouting = true)
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
        )
        .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        services.AddKendo();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "team",
                pattern: "Main/Home/{team}");

            //endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            //    name: "default",
            //    pattern: "{controller=Main}/{action=Home}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

On my `Main` controller. The action `Home` has a single parameter of `team`

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<MainController> _logger;

    public MainController(ILogger<MainController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Home(string team)
    {

        TeamModel model = new TeamModel(team);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

No matter what I do, I cannot get the `team` parameter to come through correctly as a route value.
The below configuration gives me a `404` every time, no matter the URL (`/Main/Home/MyTeam` or `/Main/Home?team=MyTeam`).
Other scenarios either give me the above issue, or the `team` parameter comes through with a `null` value..

Any help would be great - I think am probably doing something a stupid!

Comment: Why don't you use the default route and change the "team" parameter name to id?

Comment: Because I'm going through tutorials and adapting - I wanted to do it the correct way. It seemed like it should be a simple answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you add your endpoint do not have the controller and action that will be called for this route.

You can do something like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "team",
        pattern: "Main/Home/{team?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "Home" });

        //endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        //    name: "default",
        //    pattern: "{controller=Main}/{action=Home}/{id?}");
    });
```